# Excel VBA macro copy in last sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a sheet in another workbook like this

```
WB.Sheets("WorkSheet").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select)
```

So, I want that the copied sheet is the last sheet in my workbook. When I put a `1` in the last bracket it uses always a new sheet, but I want that it copies the sheet always in the same sheet, so overwrites it.
The whole thing look like that:

```
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Subfolder\" 
strFile = "copyFile.xlsx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Ret

Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(strPath & strFile)
If Ret = True Then
Else
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
End If

WB.Sheets("WorkSheet").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select)
WB.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```
WB.Sheets("WorkSheet").Copy **after:=** ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select)
```

Or

```
WB.Sheets("WorkSheet").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sheets.Count **+1** ).Select)
```